# Remove dragging functionality from item when dragged/dropped

Tags: jquery

I have a list of items that are draggable :

```
$( "li" ).draggable({
      connectToSortable: ".sortable",
      helper: "clone"
});
```

Once an item is dragged and dropped I'd like to prevent the user from dragging the same item again. Can I achieve this ? Possibly adding some css to the just dragged item ?

If the user does not drop the item (cancels the drag) then future dragging for this item should remain enabled

**Note:** I cannot remove the helper: `clone` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
$( "li" ).draggable({
           connectToSortable: ".sortable",
           helper: "clone",
           stop: function(event, ui) { $(this).draggable('disable') }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've just noticed that dragging is disabled on the item even if the user does not drop the item onto specified area. If the user does not drop the item then future dragging should remain enabled

Comment: There's a similar thing to the "stop" callback which is the "drop" callback. But it has to be configured on the "droppable" area. It will be something like this: `$( "#droppable" ).droppable({
drop: function( event, ui ) {
    ui.draggable.draggable('disable');
}
});`

Answer (score 0):

Disable the draggable while listening for the dragstop event.

```
$( ".selector" ).bind( "dragstop", function(event, ui) {
    $( ".selector" ).draggable({ disabled: true });
});
```